# For firebase app distribution, what is the maximum size of the release notes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I got an error that my release notes were too long. I can trim it down but I need to know the limit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was **16384** characters. I discovered it through manual testing so can't guarantee it's a fixed value and won't change in the future.

Unfortunately it's not mentioned in official docs (or at least I couldn't find it).

Answer (score 0):

The max for Crashlytics was 16384, so I imagine they kept that when it was migrated to Firebase.